# Scrape a library of literature with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am learning `rvest`.

I intend to scrape my search results.  Here is the webpage,

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=eliminat+matrix+effect+HPLC-ms%2Fms&filter=years.2013-2022&size=200

I looked up `html_nodes()`.  There is no what I have seen on the webpage.

What could I do?

Here is the 'body'.

```
webpage %>% html_node('body')
{html_node}
<body>
 [1] <noscript>\n  <div class="no-script-banner" id="no-script-banner">\n    <div class="warning-message">\n      <div class="warn ...
 [2] <div class="no-session-banner" id="no-session-banner" hidden>\n  <div class="warning-message">\n    <div class="warning-messa ...
 [3] <a class="usa-skipnav" href="#search-results">\n    Skip to main page content\n  </a>
 [4] <div role="complementary" id="ncov-alert-from-server" class="ncbi-alerts nCoV_shutdown converted" style="display: block;" dat ...
 [5] <div class="usa-overlay"></div>
 [6] <header class="ncbi-header" role="banner" data-section="Header"><div class="usa-grid">\n\t\t<div class="usa-width-one-whole"> ...
 [7] <div role="navigation" aria-label="access keys">\n<a id="nws_header_accesskey_0" href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/guide/bro ...
 [8] <section data-section="Alerts"><div class="ncbi-alerts-placeholder"></div>\n</section>
 [9] <a id="maincontent" aria-label="Main page content below" role="navigation"></a>
[10] <main class="search-page" id="search-page"><h1 class="usa-sr-only">Search Page</h1>\n    \n    \n\n\n\n<input type="hidden" n ...
[11] <div id="ncbi-footer">\n      <div class="literature-footer" role="complementary" title="Links to NCBI Literature Resources"> ...
[12] <script src="https://cdn.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/0399d7a0-471a-4f7d-84af-66091af9d657/CACHE/js/output.293fbf76aa18.js"></script>
[13] <script src="https://cdn.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/0399d7a0-471a-4f7d-84af-66091af9d657/CACHE/js/output.29588445dbd9.js"></script>
[14] <script>\n    ncbi.awesome.basePage.init({\n      userInfo: {\n        isLoggedIn: false,\n        username: "",\n        log ...
[15] <script type="text/javascript">\n    jQuery.getScript("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/core/alerts/alerts.js", function () {\n   ...
[16] <script defer type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/core/pinger/pinger.js"> </script>
[17] <svg class="timeline-filter-gradient" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><lineargradient id="timeline-filter-selected-g ...
[18] <script src="https://cdn.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/0399d7a0-471a-4f7d-84af-66091af9d657/CACHE/js/output.714a700656e1.js"></script>
[19] <script>\n    ncbi.awesome.searchPage.init({\n      searchQuery: "eliminat matrix effect HPLC\\u002Dms/ms",\n      searchCons ...
Not
```

Comment: Are you trying to return results with all those terms included (i.e. all search terms should appear in results)? Where do AND/OR fit with your search terms? Also, did you mis-spell part of your query and are the provided results for the correct search terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider if your search terms are correctly spelt and whether you want AND or OR between each term to appropriately set your request. Based on determining these, you might decide to use the public APIs provided to apply your query, extract pubmed ids and then request the associated documents.

API guidance: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/home/develop/api/

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

get_data <- function(link) {
  page <- read_html(link)
  data.frame(
    link = link,
    id = page %>% html_element('[title="PubMed ID"]') %>% html_text(trim = T),
    title = page %>% html_element(".heading-title") %>% html_text(trim = T),
    authors = page %>% html_elements(".full-name") %>% html_text(trim = T) %>% paste(., collapse = ', '),
    abstract = page %>% html_element("#enc-abstract") %>% html_text2()
  )
}

r <- jsonlite::read_json("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmax=200&retmode=json&term=eliminate+AND+matrix+AND+effect+AND+hplc+ms/ms&mindate=2013&maxdate=2022")
ids <- r$esearchresult$idlist

if(length(ids)>0){
  
  links <- sprintf("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/%s", ids)
  results <- map_dfr(links, get_data)
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr for sharing the codes.  I got a tibble of six papers.  I am wondering why I can't get 101 papers?

Comment: Because I have used AND to mean search for only those containing all the search terms which results in six. Swopping out with ORs results in much larger result numbers. I suspect your original request has some ORs in it.

Comment: Thank you QHarr. You make my day. I just typed in "eliminat matrix effect HPLC-ms/ms" in the search bar.  However, if I just need to scrap the search results on this webpage, why do I need to consider either "AND" or "OR" command?   

By the way, I removed the tailing 'e' from eliminate on purpose because some authors may use eliminating.  
 
My interest is to find solutions on how to eliminate/remove/decrease matrix effect in serum/tissues for LC-MS/MS method.

Comment: AND or OR determines how the query restricts items returned.  I can also write a solution just to pull from the page you are showing in the image, if wanted? API is usually a good way to go over time. Have you checked those results you are currently getting are all appropriate?

Comment: Yes, please show us the solution of ‘OR' execution, QHarr.  Regarding the scraping result using your 'AND' approach, they are appropriate.  However, I think "OR" approach would be better.  Give you an example, the paper "HPLC-MS/MS analysis of peramivir in rat plasma: Elimination of matrix effect using the phospholipid-removal solid-phase extraction method" is a good one but missed in scraping result.  I am wondering your "AND" approach does search in abstracts, we could expand such search in titles.

Comment: You would change the AND to OR in `r <- jsonlite::read_json("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmax=200&retmode=json&term=eliminate+AND+matrix+AND+effect+AND+hplc+ms/ms&mindate=2013&maxdate=2022")`

Comment: Have a look at the API docs regarding specifying where to search as you can search specific/multiple databases as well different publication types.

Comment: Thank you QHarr.  I will take a look at API.  By the way, I replaced "AND" with "OR", and got 200 rows.  I want to ask you a favor.  Could you please teach me how to 'fish' beyond just get fish?  I am taking a course on web scraping with R at DataCamp.  How did you learn web scraping? Any suggestion?

Comment: I started with a language I knew very well and literally went through every StackOverflow question I could find. I supplemented that with YouTube videos and reading articles/blogs. I subscribed to several courses but found them generally teaching poor/bad/out of date approaches IMO. I widened my knowledge by reading and trying questions across a wider variety of languages. The approaches don't change much, only the limitations of the language and syntax/language idioms, as it is more often than not about understanding how a webpage is being updated/structured

Comment: For R I study the documentation relating to packages, rely on existing knowledge from other languages, learning from answers given by other users in R + `<insert web-scraping related tag here>`  You need sound basic html/JavaScript knowledge and some idea about modern web frameworks. There are some links in my profile.

Comment: I appreciate your help, QHarr.  I managed to retrieve the year, the name of the journal, and the DOI of each piece of literature.  You opened my eyes to a better way of efficient literature search.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I want to scrap application notes at the Agilent website. Here is an example. [Agilent application note search results](https://www.agilent.com/search/?N=129&Ntt=steroids&catdd=1).   I cannot find the file name of each application note in 'Element' in the developer tool.  I am also wondering if there is an available tool to search keywords in each pdf file?

Comment: Sorry QHarr, I can't find a way of sharing my screenshot when adding a comment.  It is inconvenient.

Comment: `read_html('https://www.agilent.com/search/?N=129&Ntt=steroids&catdd=1') %>% html_elements('.media-object a') %>% html_attr('href')`  ?

Comment: For keywords you can use settings for `corpus` within pdftools.

Comment: Thank you QHarr for walking me through the process.  With your hint, I got them with ```%>% html_elements('.media-heading a') %>% html_text()```, the document title.
Regarding scraping on the Agilent website, I could not use your approach deployed on the NIH.gov website.  Any reason?

Comment: Oops... sorry, I gave you the path to extract the documents themselves. With respect to your next question, please open a new question explaining the problem, include your code and show where stuck. Remember to include expected output v actual.

Comment: Hi QHarr, I opened a new question "Scrape the Agilent website for application notes with rvest".

Answer (score 3):

We can get the title of search results by

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.docsum-title') %>% html_text() %>% str_remove_all('\\n')

  [1] "                HPLC-MS/MS analysis of peramivir in rat plasma: Elimination of matrix effect using the phospholipid-removal solid-phase extraction method.              "                                                                                                                                             
  [2] "                Development of matrix effect-free MISPE-UHPLC-MS/MS method for determination of lovastatin in Pu-erh tea, oyster mushroom, and red yeast rice.
```

And links to articles by

```
df = url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.docsum-title') %>% html_attr('href') 

paste0('https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov', df)

  [1] "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28976569/" "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28410522/" "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27491846/"
  [4] "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31532096/" "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31288535/" "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29433096/"
```

You can see the node `.docsum-title` and link beside it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Nad.  what is the process of identifying ".docsum-title" is the node where titles are stored?  If I need abstract under each paper, where do I look at?

Comment: Yeah under node `.docsum-title` the title are stored. If we need the abstract then wee have loop through each of the link and under node `.abstract-content selected` the abstract is stored.

Comment: Thank you Nad.  Could you please walk me through how I know the titles are stored under node .docsum-title?

Comment: Modified the answer to include image of node.

Comment: Thank you Nad,  I figured it out to get the image that you share.  I am thrilled at learning such web scraping tools to save my time on literature search.

Comment: Hi Nad, how did you paste the screenshot?  I tried two approaches: 1) 
![screenshot](D:/.../Images/Screenshot 2021-12-13 080908.png, 2) CRTL+G

Comment: You can simply click on Image button which is beside the curly brackets or else refer here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Comment: Hi Nad, I am looking for the solution that you added a screenshot  in the Comment when you responded to me.

Comment: @pinawa I am not able to get you. You can't add screenshot in the comment.